# Проблема авторизации в Instagram с помощью InstaSharper

Tags: c#, api

Пишу консольное приложение "Бот instagram" по видеоуроку https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9leg398KAw , с использованием пакета InstaSharper.

Листинг:

```
    private const string username = "login";
    private const string password = "password";

    private static UserSessionData user;
    private static IInstaApi api;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        user = new UserSessionData();
        user.UserName = username;
        user.Password = password;

        Login();
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static async void Login()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.instagram.com/?hl=ru");

        api = InstaApiBuilder.CreateBuilder()
            .SetUser(user)
            .UseLogger(new DebugLogger(LogLevel.Exceptions))
            .SetRequestDelay(RequestDelay.FromSeconds(1, 10))
            .UseHttpClient(client)
            .Build();

        var loginRequest = await api.LoginAsync();

        if (loginRequest.Succeeded)
            Console.WriteLine("Logged in!");
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"Error Logging in\n{loginRequest.Info.Message}");
    }
```

При запуске приложения вызывается ошибка с описанием:

> Challenge required

т.е. требуется какое-то подтверждение. 
Натыкался на статьи https://qna.habr.com/q/565067 , но не знаю как решить данную проблему.
В момент запуска приложения c#, на телефоне в приложении Instagram приходит предупреждение что замечен подозрительный вход и просит подтвердить кнопками "Это я" и "Это не я". Пробовал отключать двухфакторную авторизацию. Проблема осталась прежняя.

Прошу помочь в решении. Что необходимо прописать в коде чтобы авторизоваться?

Comment: Вообще "Challenge required" означает, что нужно подтвердить email или телефон путем отправки на него кода и ввода куда надо.

Comment: Ну это понятно) Но как реализовать данное подтверждение в c#?